# Moving items in content editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

When moving items in Content Editor, using buttons from menu, are created versions for all items on the current level that don't have versions on the current language version.

This is a problem for items in two languages and some items have versions only on one language.  We have content on Standard values so when items are published $name appear on front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. I guess your solution is before 6.4. 
Please check here release history for Sitecore 6.4  :  http://sdn.sitecore.net/products/sitecore%20v5/sitecore%20cms%206/releasenotes/changelog/release%20history%20sc64.aspx

When performing any of the following operations on an item that did not have any versions in the current language, the system would create an empty version:
When specifying publishing restrictions for the entire item. (338784)
When a user set or cleared the archive date. (338850)
When changing the sort order or items, including setting the subitem sorting. (336514)
When using the "Move To" command to move an item. (336514)

If you can't update to 6.4 you need to modify  next commands with your own commands .

```
<command name="item:movedown" type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MoveDown,Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<command name="item:movefirst" type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MoveFirst,Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<command name="item:movelast" type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MoveLast,Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<command name="item:moveto" type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MoveTo,Sitecore.Kernel"/>
```